# How to chunk n segments from a nestled list

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists, chunking

I'm trying to chunk 100 lists from a nestled list.  I have looked looked through multiple examples on Stack Overflow, but I still cannot get something working correctly.

My primary list is named data_to_insert and it contains other lists.  I would like to extract (chunk) 100 lists from the primary nestled list.

How do I accomplish this?

This is my current code, which doesn't work as needed.

```
def divide_chunks(l, n):
   for i in range(0, len(l), n):
      yield l[i:i + n]

n = 100
x = list(divide_chunks(data_to_insert, 100))
```

Nestled list example:

```
data_to_insert = [['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
 ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
 ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
 ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
 ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
 ...
 [thousands of others lists go here]]
```

Desired output is another list (sliced_data), which contains 100 lists from the nestled list (data_to_insert).

```
sliced_data = [['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
 ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'], 
 ...
 [98 more lists go here]]
```

I need to loop through the nestled list, data_to_insert until it's empty.

Comment: Can you please share your current output and format in which you expect your final output.

Comment: I have posted examples of my input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random` to select `100` random nested lists from your given list.

This will output `3` random nested list from original list,

```
import random

l = [[1,2], [3,4], [1,1], [2,3], [3,5], [0,0]]
print(random.sample(l, 3))


# output,
[[3, 4], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

If you do not want a list output then replace `print(random.sample(l, 3))` with `print(*random.sample(l, 3))`,

```
# output,
[1, 2] [2, 3] [1, 1]
```

If you just want first `100` nested lists then do,

```
print(l[:100])
```

Comment: Random is a possibility to solve this this problem.  I will explore how to use this with my nestled list, which contains 10000 nestled lists.

Comment: you can just copy and paste above code and it will work. just replace `3` with `100`. Does this help?

Comment: Based on your comment, I was able to design another example to accomplish the task of chunking n lists from a nestled list.

Answer (score 1):

If i did understand your question correctly, you need first to flatten your list of list then create a chunks of it. Here is an example using `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools module` along with the code you've used to create chunks:

```
from itertools import chain

def chunks(elm, length):
    for k in range(0, len(elm), length):
        yield elm[k: k + length]


my_list = [['item{}'.format(j) for j in range(7)]] * 1000
flattened = list(chain.from_iterable(my_list))

chunks = list(chunks(flattened, 100))

print(len(chunks[10]))
```

Output:

```
100
```

Comment: Can you explain this piece?  my_list = [['item{}'.format(j) for j in range(7)]] * 1000

Comment: This will create the list of lists you've added in your question. Try it in your terminal.

Comment: I have tested the code, without that snippet of code and it flattened my nestled list, which is a problem.  I needed to extract 100 of the nestled lists.  How do I obtain 100 nestled lists without flattening the lists?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex don't use `chain` and you'll have a nested lists.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up and thanks for originally answering my question.  Stack Overflow has become an invaluable resource in my coding writing efforts.

Answer (score 0):

After some time-consuming research, I developed a solution that worked.  The solution below loops through a list of lists and extract 100 lists.

```
# Verifies that the list data_to_insert isn't empty
if len(data_to_insert) > 0:

  # Obtains the length of the data to insert.
  # The length is the number of sublists
  # contained in the main nestled list.
  data_length = len(data_to_insert)

  # A loop counter used in the
  # data insert process.
  i = 0

  # The number of sublists to slice
  # from the main nestled list in
  # each loop.
  n = 100

  # This loop execute a set of statements
  # as long as the condition below is true
  while i < data_length:

    # Increments the loop counter
    if len(data_to_insert) < 100:
      i += len(data_to_insert)
    else:
       i += 100

    # Slices 100 sublists from the main nestled list.
    sliced_data = data_to_insert[:n]

    # Verifies that the list sliced_data isn't empty
    if len(sliced_data) > 0:

      # Removes 1000 sublists from the main nestled list.
      data_to_insert = data_to_insert[n:]

      ##################################
      do something with the sliced_data
      ##################################

      # Clears the list used to store the
      # sliced_data in the insertion loop.
      sliced_data.clear()
      gc.collect()

   # Clears the list used to store the
   # data elements inserted into the
   # database.
   data_to_insert.clear()
   gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a second method to accomplish my objective, which is based on [Sufiyan Ghori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149423/sufiyan-ghori) suggestion of using `random.`

```
if len(my_nestled_list) > 0:

  # Obtains the length of the data to insert.
  # The length is the number of sublists
  # contained in the main nestled list.
  data_length = len(my_nestled_list))

  # A loop counter used in the
  # data insert process.
  i = 0

  # The number of sublists to slice
  # from the main nestled list in
  # each loop.
  n = 100

  # This loop execute a set of statements
  # as long as the condition below is true
  while i < data_length:

    # Increments the loop counter
    if len(my_nestled_list)) < 100:
      i += len(my_nestled_list))
    else:
      i += 100

    # Uses list comprehension to randomly select 100 lists 
    # from the nestled list.  
    random_sample_of_100 = [my_nestled_list)[i] for i in sorted(random.sample(range(len(my_nestled_list))), n))]

   print (random_sample_of_100)
```